# Make AJAX Request to WCF service with POST

Tags: c#, json, ajax, wcf, post

I'm getting this error on AJAX Request to WCF with method POST?

HTTP/1.1 504 Fiddler - Receive Failure
Date: Sat, 03 Dec 2016 20:38:19 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: close
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate
Timestamp: 18:38:19.757

[Fiddler] ReadResponse() failed: The server did not return a complete response for this request. Server returned 0 bytes.

CHROME RETURN
jquery.min.js:4 POST http://localhost:70/SiteService.svc/ConsultaMaisPessoaFisica net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

I'm getting several errors with OPTIONS and POST method that came at same request.

Here is my code:

Contract

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
DadosPF ConsultaMaisPessoaFisica(string login, string token, string cpf);
```

Method Implementation

```
public DadosPF ConsultaMaisPessoaFisica(string login, string token, string cpf)
        {
            DadosPF info = new DadosPF();
            try
            {
                using (MailingData data = new MailingData())
                {
                    if (!ValidarToken(login, token))
                    {
                        info.Erro = "Token inválido";
                        return info;
                    }
                    if (!data.ValidarAcessoServico(login, WebService.MaisPessoaFisica))
                    {
                        info.Erro = "Serviço não esta ativo para este login";
                        return info;
                    }
                    if (!data.ValidarConsumoServico(login, WebService.MaisPessoaFisica))
                    {
                        info.Erro = "Limite máximo de consumo excedido";
                        return info;
                    }

                    cpf = BaseData.OnlyNumbers(cpf);

                    var dadosCadastrais = data.ConsultaCadastroPF(cpf).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (dadosCadastrais == null)
                    {
                        info.Erro = "Nenhum registro encontrado";
                        return info;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        info = new DadosPF();
                        info.DadosCadastrais = dadosCadastrais;
                        info.Enderecos = data.ConsultarEnderecosPF(dadosCadastrais.cod_pessoa_fisica);
                        info.Contatos = data.ConsultarContatosPF(dadosCadastrais.cod_pessoa_fisica);
                        info.Parentesco = data.ConsultarParentescoPF(dadosCadastrais.cod_pessoa_fisica);
                        info.Veiculos = data.ConsultaVeiculos(dadosCadastrais.cod_pessoa_fisica, 0);
                        info.Empresas = data.ConsultarEmpresasPorSocio(cpf);
                        data.AtualizarConsumo(login, WebService.MaisPessoaFisica);
                    }

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Logger.Error(ex.Message, ex);
                throw new Exception("Falha no metodo ConsultaMaisPessoaFisica: " + ex.ToString());
            }
            return info;
        }
```

GLOBAL.ASAX

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authorization, Origin, Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
            }
        }
```

WEB.CONFIG

```
<system.serviceModel>

    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WebScriptBehavior">
          <enableWebScript />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="webHttpBehavior">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="mex">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
      multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />

    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="MailingService_Endpoint" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
            maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfVisualFix.MailingService">
        <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MailingService_Endpoint"
          name="MailingService_Endpoint" contract="WcfVisualFix.IMailingService" />
      </service>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="mex" name="WcfVisualFix.SiteService">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="webHttpBehavior"
          binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WcfVisualFix.ISiteService" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

AJAX CALL

```
$("#btnConsultar").click(function () {

            $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost:70/SiteService.svc/ConsultaMaisPessoaFisica",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
                data: JSON.stringify({ login: $("#txtLogin").val(), token: $("#txtToken").val(), cpf: $("#txtCPF").val() }),
                dataType: "json",
                success:
                    function (res) {
                        $("#txtNome").val(res.d.Nome);
                    },
                error:
                    function (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    }
            });
```

Comment: what error message are you getting? Did you try to use something like postman first to see if your api is even working? Did you try to debug anything?

Comment: @AndreiDragotoniu I got the error on fiddler, edited on the question. I had to make many changes on my code to fix previous erros, On of the reasons is that I had to remove the Method with attribute "WebInvoke(Method="OPTIONS")]". I saw this as an "workaround" solution to got it worked with POST. Second, I removed custom header from WebConfig, since I was doing it on global.asax "BeginRequest" event. But for now, I'm getting this error on fiddler: ReadResponse() failed: The server did not return a complete response for this request. Server returned 0 bytes.

Comment: Other problem that I couldn't fix is that debbugin on WcfTestClient is not working. It doesn´t load the service methods from metadata.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the answer.
WCF wasn't able to serialize some objects to JSON.
In my case I had a class with attribute "DataContract" with IsReference=true.
I could get the answer only by enabling WCF Trace in Web CONFIG.

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel"
              switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
              propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add name="traceListener"
              type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
              initializeData= "c:\temp\Traces.svclog" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
  </system.diagnostics>
```